# Enabling forced WWW redirection with CloudFlare drops POST requests

Tags: php, redirect, cloudflare, dreamhost

I'm not sure where to start on this one. I have a shared hosting account with DreamHost. While transferring my website to PHP 7.3, I decided to try to enable free CloudFlare account, which for some bizarre reason required forcing redirection of all URLs to WWW:

[image]

But after I've done that, such redirect seems to drop all POST requests.

I tried to contact tech support at DreamHost but they weren’t even able to understand what I’m talking about and gave me a generic reply that CloudFlare requires WWW redirection. So I'm left to look for a solution elsewhere.

Here's an example.  In the following PHP script, if I load it as: `https://www.example.com/test.php` it will result in the `POST` request being dropped when I click `SEND` button in it. But if I change `method` from `POST` to `GET`, it works fine. Or, if I add www to the `action` tag in html as in `action="https://www.example.com/test.php"` it also works.

Any idea how to fix this redirection issue?

```
//Hosted as:
//     https://www.example.com/test.php

<?
$name = isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : '';

if(!$name)
{
    echo('<html><body>'.
    '<form method="post" action="https://example.com/test.php">'.  //Note that I removed www. part from the `action` tag
    '<input type="text" name="name" value="My name">'.
    '<input type="submit" value="SEND">'.
    '</form>'.
    '</body></html>');
}
else
{
    echo('name='.htmlentities($name).'<br>');
}
?>
```

Comment: so if your website is `www` required , why don't you just www in action ?

Comment: @Abolix: I have old apps (downloaded by my customers) that do not use www in URLs to connect to my website. So my APIs break down because they don't receive any data in the POST request. (What you see in my post above is just an example, or a proof-of-concept of the issue.)

Comment: it's because it will redirect the url and in redirection , your post data will be gone . I think it's better to try for removing the www ( contact your host or cloudflare ) . because i don't think there is a way to pass post data in this situation  .

Comment: You can't redirect POST requests with 301 or 302, only 307. Check what your provider is doing. This isn't a programming question so would probably be better off on [sf]. See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect